# Implement JS window.timer in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, timer

I am writing to clarify a general question regarding AJAX implementation with JS and ASP.net
Let's start from a simple example as:

```
<h1>Test page</h1>
<p id="text">Click Here</p>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("text");
    var i = 0
    placeholder.innerText = "Hello, World!";

    window.timer = window.setInterval(
        function () {
            i++;
            placeholder.innerText = i;

            if (i == 10 ) {
                    window.clearInterval(window.timer);
            }
       }, 1000)    
  }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lucamauri/cex82q23/

In the very simple page shown, the `<p>` will change text according to the variable `i` that is incremented every 1000ms by the `window.timer`.
The variable is preserved on the cycle even if the content is reloaded and everything works just fine.

Now, I would like to implement something similar in ASP.net and it seems to me extremely difficult comparatively to JS.
I started creating a update panel with a timer, but they are not preserving variable between update interval, so I should also setup a system to save the session variable and so on.

Is this really more difficult to do in native ASP.net or I am simply missing something basilar here?

Thanks for all the help you'll provide.

Comment: Your .net code runs on the server, not the client; what is it that you hope to achieve by doing this in ASP.net?

Comment: @Pointy the real project is about a watch-like SVG graphics that ticks at a user-input interval. I over-simplified the whole thing here just to make a quick example.
As i only know baisc JS, but I know better VB.net, I would write the project using native VB.net code in a ASP.net solution.

Comment: Right, but your animation will be something happening on the *client computer* - the machine hosting the web browser. In order to implement this in VB.net, you'd need continuous communication between the client and the server-side code, and that'd *still* require JavaScript on the client to coordinate things.

Comment: @Pointy thanks, I see your point. So, bottom line, there is no way to do such a thing with the server-based ASP.net: it's a basic technology related feature, not my lack of knowledge, right?

Comment: Yes - I mean, if there's work do be done in order to compute each new blob of SVG code, then it *might* make sense for the client to fetch updates from the server, but what you're describing is probably something you could do purely in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy if you like to summarize the discussion in an answer, then I will vote it. Again, thanks for your help